# Add new class to YOLOv3-tiny/v4-tiny in darknet

Tags: computer-vision, object-detection, yolo, darknet, yolov4

I'd like to ask you if it's possible to extend/add new class to pre-trained yolov3/v4-tiny model. I need to add shoe. Let's say it would be 81st object. My expectation was to add new class to coco.names. Txt files should have the first number 81 as 81-st class and plus  coordinates of tag.
Also cfg file I would edit for 1 class. But this idea have weak-points 1 class in cfg... 81 classes in coco.names.... I simply can't imagine how to do it, or is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use pretrained backbone like [this](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet#pre-trained-models) (e.g., yolov4-tiny.conv.29), edit filters and classes number in *.cfg file according to [this](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet#how-to-train-to-detect-your-custom-objects). More links to pretrained models are in ["Releases"](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/releases/tag/yolov4).

And than run the training process:

```
./darknet detector train ~/*.data ~/*.cfg ~/yolov4-tiny.conv.29
```

where "yolov4-tiny.conv.29" are weights of pretrained model up to 29th layer